# Annoying state transition from Ionic login page

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

For the login page of my Ionic-framework app, I hide the nav-bar with `hide-nav-bar="true"` as does every example I have seen. The problem is, when logging in and the page changes, the nav-bar appears for a momment before the transition to the next page is completed.

I'm using `$state.go('page');` for transitions.

This seems like a bug in `Ionic`, but is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: have you tried to set it hidden by default and activate it only on purpose ?

Comment: try using $location.path instead